# Seeking ArcView 3 extension named createcolors.avx?

Tags: extensions, basic-license-level, arcview-3

Can anybody provide me with a copy of the file "createcolors.avx"?

Answer (score 3):

GIS Stack Exchange is not the place to be requesting very old ArcView Extensions. Unfortunately the old ArcScript website got blitzed and ESRI did not port over the majority of the tools. There is a thread on [geonet](https://community.esri.com/message/630979-please-restore-arcscripts) which you must post on contacting Jimmy Barry and request it there, if they still have it, they will upload it as a zip file.